# Can you require infinite modules in node?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project which needs to load specific module based on url, and there are a lot of modules, I'm wondering is it going to blow up the memory if you keep requiring modules? If it is, is there anyway to free up memory after each module is executed? Or is there anyway better than requiring modules? like fs.readFile then eval it?

Answer (score 0):

You can load as many modules as you want, but the hardware limitations will still be there. If your memory is going to blow up - will depend on the memory consumption of each module, the tasks your program is doing, and the amount of RAM you have. If you keep on requiring modules just to test if it breaks, I am sure it will break after a certain number of modules are loaded into the memory.

When you use memory intensive modules, you can scope them i.e. require() them inside a function like: to make sure they are unloaded from memory after the operation is complete.

```
// this code does image manipulation
function resizeImage(filename, cb) {
    require('gm').open(filename).size(function (err, size) {
        console.log(size);
        // do something else with the image

        cb(null);
        // gm is queued for garbage collection
        // after this operation
    });
}
```

`fs.readFile` and eval will not be better than `require()`.

If you have all memory optimizations in place and still your RAM is not enough, the application will break, and you will need to scale up your machine.

Comment: When you load a module, it gets added to the module cache so I think all that's going away with GC is basically a reference to that module: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching